# Problems in GoProHERO6 Audio RAW

Tags: audio-recording

GoPro Hero6 creates a separate .wav file along with the .mp4 video. But my .wav-s are all too silent I can barely hear them. As the excerpt from HERO6 manual shows, I followed the Protune instructions marked in RED for audio post-processing. How will I know if the .wav-s are eligible enough for post-production and mix and is there some kind of 'trick' sound editors can do with this?

[image: Manual]

This separate audio file that HERO6 creates seems to have some kind of bug.
Tyler, I don't own an audio editing app. My plan is to find a good designer for that. I am only a video editor, doing it in FCPX, so I am attaching the screenshot here of how it looks like on my timeline. This is a synced clip imported from Pluraleyes.

[image: FPCX screenshot]

Update: I've made a Low-Med-High test too
[image: FCPX Screenshot 2]

Comment: They can ramp the gain, but it will bring the noise floor with it. Best to get your levels right at the start.

Comment: what does one of these wav files look like when you open in an audio editor?

Comment: GoProHERO6 isn't made much for the PRO Audio recording. The professional Mics to record audio are not introduced in this device. You'd have to invest in the additional audio equipment. There is always the Hi-Fi sound of the recording wind & noise in question when recording LIVE. I'm asking if there are any XLR connectors to plug better microphones on the GoPro. As a musician I would wish & appreciate such options/interface the most. Regards!

Comment: i'm curious if whatever you're trying to record is just super quiet, and the mp4 file is "louder" because of the auto gain compensation. Can you do a little test with the "high" option selected and see if the resulting two audio tracks look similar?

Comment: The content I recorded was of normal loudness, so no 'super-quiet' conditions. I did the medium test, and the same thing happened. Super-quiet  audio output in .wav

Comment: I tested the three options. This is how it looks like.

Comment: oh dang...how does the "high" setting .wav file sound? is it crisp and clear or mushy and noisy?

Comment: High setting is pretty much the same as .mp4 sound. It is not really crisp and clear, rather muffled and full od bass. Ok Tyler, thanks for help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the GoPro is simply applying massive gain to the audio when recording the video's track.  The waveforms look very similar but scaled way down, but signal to noise floor levels look roughly similar for only having a waveform to look at.  Looking at the high processing, you can see that gained up, it's almost identical.  It appears like everything is likely working as intended and your original audio levels are just very, very low.

Doing a bit of digging online seems to confirm this.  The camera appears to use an extremely low level for the recording to avoid clipping even in extreme situations and then applies gain to normalize the level up.  You should still be able to get the audio out, it will just be using a very low bit depth since only a small portion of the actual range of values is being used.